# nicEdit editor ang mysql

Tags: php, image, nicedit, richtext

i am trying to create rich text box in PHP...   i am using nicEdit for that.. actually i am having content that contain **Text** as well as **Image** both together in 1 field named content.. i am using datatype **longtext** i am inserting some text and 1 image like this: [image] into database it's shows like

```
    Som<b>e Initial C</b>ontent was in t<u>his textarea rjhj</u>rh &nbsp;<img src="p.jpg" alt="image alttext" align="none">

Some Initial Content was in this textarea kjkeur ewurouw45u4395u32 32u532i5&nbsp;<img src="p.jpg" alt="" align="none">&nbsp;eiueiwurie
```

but into display page it shows me like **other tag is working but not img tag**

[image]

i am doing like this

```
$category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
//echo
 $content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
//echo
 $subject=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
$sql="INSERT INTO posts(subject,content,category,post_date)
    values ('$subject','$content','$category',NOW())";
```

**for display**

```
$content = $row['content'];
echo "<td><font color='black' size=2>".$content."</font>";
```

what is wrong i am doing? or what is i am missing?(i may need more than 1 image also) plz help me to solve this problem...
Thanks in advance
Pragna.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the image to separate Path and insert the path value as separate column in Post table.

The Problem is if you have more than 2 pictures in your content.

Refer this link for more info : http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/